# iterating localstorage while making ajax call

Tags: javascript, local-storage

If I have several items in localstorage that I need to iterate and do some operation, I know this code will fail skipping alternate items

```
for (var i = 0, len = localStorage.length; i < len; i++)
{
    var key = localStorage.key(i);
    localStorage.removeItem(key);
}
```

Now, keeping in mind js is single threaded; if I have something like

```
for (var i = 0, len = localStorage.length; i < len; i++)
{
    var key = localStorage.key(i);
    ajaxHttpAndSuccessCallback(function f(){localStorage.removeItem(key)});
}
```

Where ajaxHttpAndSuccessCallback makes some ajax call and calls the parameter function in case of success. Is that guaranteed to work/not work? Browser dependent? ..?

Comment: Have you tried `for` loop where item is removed from `localStorage` at `success` of ajax call ? What is result ?

Comment: do you really wanted to remove all items from `localStorage` object in such a way?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest no .. but I would still like to know what can happen if I do

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `ajax` within an IIFE with `i` passed as variable to

```
for (var i = 0, len = localStorage.length; i < len; i++) {
  (function(index) {
    var key = localStorage.key(index);
    ajaxHttpAndSuccessCallback(function f(){localStorage.removeItem(key)});
  }(i));
}
```

Comment: Or just `forEach`..I guess!

Comment: @RayonDabre _"Or just `forEach`"_ Not certain where `.forEach()` would be utilized ?

Comment: Will `localStorage.forEach(function(){ ...})` fail ? Correct me If I am missing something..

Comment: @RayonDabre `.forEach()` is a method of `Array.prototype` . Have you tried `localStorage.forEach(function() {})` ?

Comment: I was reading `localStorage` as variable holding array stored in `localStorage`.. Got it!

Comment: @RayonDabre `localStorage.getItem()` returns a `DOMString` , see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem

Comment: localStorage is an object like storage

Comment: @guest271314, Aah..That much I know.. I assumed OP has parsed it.. Was not aware of _localStorage is an object like storage_

Comment: @guest271314 I have tried and it works, but my question is more along the lines of whether there is any form of *guarantee* that the loop to iterate over the entire storage will complete before there is any callback from the ajax success (and the localstorage item is removed). If there is any callback then obviously removeItem will get called and localStorage.length would become less

Comment: @saugata _"I have tried and it works, but my question is more along the lines of whether there is any form of guarantee that the loop to iterate over the entire storage will complete before there is any callback from the ajax success (and the localstorage item is removed)."_ No, not using approach at `js` at Question. ajax is asynchronous. Though it should be possible to iterate the `localStorage` object first, store the item to remove in a function created within the loop, then call the functions at a later time, either in sequence or individually. What are you trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 1):

- I asked: "do you really wanted to remove all items from `localStorage` object in such a way? "
- You answered: "no .. but I would still like to know what can happen if I do"

`localStorage` is an object like storage. And if you are treating it as an array you will not be able to remove all its items in the way you have presented in the question.
 Array's `length` property is a "***live***" property.
Consider the following example which uses `for` loop from your question:

```
    localStorage.clear();
    localStorage.setItem(0, 'red');
    localStorage.setItem(1, 'Helvetica');
    localStorage.setItem(2, 'myCat.png');

    console.log(localStorage);  // Storage {0: "red", 1: "Helvetica", 2: "myCat.png", length: 3}

    for (var i = 0, len = localStorage.length;  i < len; i++)
    {
        var key = localStorage.key(i);
        localStorage.removeItem(key);        
    }

    console.log(localStorage);  // Storage {1: "Helvetica", length: 1}
```

**As for ajax calls:** in such case:
Sending ajax requests in synchronous loop is bad approach. Use "success" callback to send request and remove next `localStorage` item till the storage is not empty.

```
function getData()
{
    var len = localStorage.length;
    // constructing xmlhttprequest, adding headers
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.onload = function(){ // when the request is loaded
        var key = localStorage.key(len-1);
        localStorage.removeItem(key);
        if (len) getData();
    };
    ...
    httpRequest.send();
}
```

Comment: So .. the first part of my question already says that if item is removed in the for loop then it would skip items .. that's not in doubt. I want to know what might happen if I do the item removal as part of callback of an ajax request that was triggered from the loop ... in context of event driven single threaded model of js

Comment: while that's good to know, it still does not answer my question. The code given by you is better, but question is what would happen with the code I had in the question text .. so +1 but not accepted yet :)

Comment: @saugata, it's simple - the code in your question will mostly give you the unpredictable(unexpected) results, because you are calling asynchronous requests in synchronous loop. That loop can easily end up much faster than you got and processed all responses from ajax requests. You have no guarantee with "such" code